# Changing base with functors instead of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

It is known that given two schemes $X$ and $S$ over a field $k$, one may define the base-change scheme $X_S$ to be the $S$-scheme $X\times_k S$, with structural morphism the projection $X_S\to S$.

Now let $F$ be a contravariant functor from the category of schemes over a field $k$ to the category of sets, and let $S$ be a scheme over $k$. How can we define the functor $F_S$. I tried setting $F_S = F \times_{h_{Spec(k)}} h_S$, where $h_{Spec(k)}$ and $h_S$ are the functors of points of $Spec(k)$ and $S$, but this failed to satisfy well knows results.

Another way to define such a functor would be to set $F_S(T)=F(T)$ for any $S$-scheme $T$, where in the left hand side, we think of $T$ as being an $S$-scheme, and in the right hand side we view it as a $k$-scheme. However, I'm not sure whether this works or not.

Is there a reference where such constructions are discussed?

Comment: It's just $F_S(T) = F(T)$ and this follows directly from the universal property of the fiber product.

Comment: What is $F_S$ supposed to be – a presheaf on the category of $k$-schemes or a presheaf on the category of $S$-schemes?

Comment: Dear @QiaochuYuan, note that the functor F need not be representable

Comment: @ZhenLin I think it's supposed to be the latter, just like the scheme $X_S$ is viewed as an $S$-scheme.

Comment: The base change has the property that morphisms $T \to F_S$ ($T$ identified with its representable functor as an $S$-scheme) are in natural bijection with morphisms $T \to F$ (now $T$ is identified with its representable functor as a $k$-scheme). So it is as Qiaochu says.

Comment: Could you elaborate which "well known results" are not satisfied, and why?